# How to create custom url button

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking

How can I capture the standard object case 15 digit ID, and my situation is I want to create a custom button url which is having EDIT standard button features. 
In my case object, when I click on edit button the status field should change to 'New', but it not happening with standard edit button where I need to change manually from status A to status 'New'. So I thought I can create a custom button and when I click on it, it auto-populate the status field value to'New'. So for these reason I want to use custom button. !!!!Any Suggestions is really Appreciate.

Comment: Can you be more specific about functions you want?
Because if you want only change in status than you need trigger not button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom button and add some custom parameters to the edit url.  The url would look something like this:
`https://cs11.salesforce.com/{!Case.Id}/e?retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&nameofyourstatusfield=New`

To find out the name of your status field, view source on the edit page and look for the name attribute.  It should look something like this: `<select id="cas7" name="cas7" tabindex="2"></select>`

So if the name of your status field is "cas7", the url would look like:
`https://cs11.salesforce.com/{!Case.Id}/e?retURL=%2F{!Case.Id}&cas7=New`

Answer (score 0):

If you want just change status please create before update trigger.

Comment: How about workflows?

Comment: workflow = additional update :)

Comment: not really different than a trigger .. both happen after the record is submitted from the page.